# Configure Proxy under AWS KinesisAsyncClient in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-agent

I need to configure proxies for the Kinesis client. Currently I m using KinesisAsyncClient object for performing async operations on the kinesis stream.
After a bit of a search over internet, I came to a conclusion that there is no proper resource which helps to configure proxies over async clients.

So is there any way we can configure the proxy `host`, `port`, `username`, `password` and `non-proxy-hosts` under the KinesisAsyncClient object.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to set Proxy host and port and pass to the KinesisAsyncClient using the following code:

```
    String hostString="127.0.0.1";
    int port=8080;
    ProxyConfiguration proxyConfiguration =ProxyConfiguration.builder().host(hostString).port(port).build();
    
    SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder().proxyConfiguration(proxyConfiguration).build();
    

    KinesisAsyncClient client = KinesisAsyncClient.builder().httpClient(httpClient).build();
```

Please note I have set a sample hostString and Port.

Hope this helps.